# Timeline view: App to browse photos by date/time located in multiple folders?

Tags: file-management

This may be a trivial one -- I am looking for an application (Windows or MacOS) in which I can browse my photos by date/time (taken/created), even though they do not necessarily reside in the same folder.  Any suggestions?

Background: I have my photos organized in different folders, e.g., per event/date, sometimes with subfolders for different devices (e.g., DSLR1, compact camera).  Now, especially for events where I've used different cameras in parallel (or for my "catch-all" mobile phone backup folder), I would like to browse all the pictures in the sequence of when they have been taken (ignoring potential time drifts), i.e., like a **timeline**.

Additional points:

- I prefer not to use a cloud based solution, but from a local directory or NAS-share
- I do not want to reorganize my directories (especially not the mobile phone backup folder), but just have a merged view.
- Free or paid is OK (as long as it is reasonable, ideally under $100)

Picasa proved to be good for this -- but has been discontinued.  I am looking for alternatives and would be grateful for any suggestions/pointers.  Thanks!

Comment: Should they be free or paid ones are OK too?

Comment: Good question -- both is fine (updated the description). Happy to pay for useful tools.

Answer (score 2):

This may be an overkill for just this requirement, but **Adobe Photoshop Lightroom** achieves this (and a lot more).

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 10 "Photos" Application can achieve exactly what you want. You just need to add all your photo locations to the app by using `More > Settings > Sources`. More Details [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17194/windows-10-see-all-your-photos).

Answer (score 0):

Directory Opus can do this with its search functionality. Directory Opus is a file manager for windows. Frankly I think it's the best one out there. It's insanely customizable, fast, and can also replace Windows Explorer. I'm also a programmer and it makes my life so much easier. I have no affiliation with them.